# How to evenly shrink items in layout to make space for more items

Tags: qt, layout, qml

Initially, I have four items with a specific size. Once a 5th item gets added, I would like to shrink the size of all items to make space inside the layout.

```
Window {
 width: 640
 height: 480
 visible: true
 id: root

 Item {
    id: col
    width: 300
    height: 200
    anchors.centerIn: parent

    RowLayout {
        id: row
        spacing: 10
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        Rectangle {
            Layout.minimumWidth: 30
            Layout.preferredWidth: 60
            Layout.preferredHeight: 20
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            color: "red"
        }
        Rectangle {
            Layout.minimumWidth: 30
            Layout.preferredWidth: 60
            Layout.preferredHeight: 20
            color: "blue"
            Layout.fillWidth: true
        }
        Rectangle {
            Layout.minimumWidth: 30
            Layout.preferredWidth: 60
            Layout.preferredHeight: 20
            color: "green"
            Layout.fillWidth: true
        }
        Rectangle {
            Layout.minimumWidth: 30
            Layout.preferredWidth: 60
            Layout.preferredHeight: 20
            color: "green"
            Layout.fillWidth: true
        }
        Rectangle {
            Layout.minimumWidth: 30
            Layout.preferredWidth: 60
            Layout.preferredHeight: 20
            color: "blue"
        }
    }
}

// for visualization
Rectangle {
    width: col.width
    height: col.height
    x: col.x
    y: col.y
    color: "black"
    opacity: 0.3
 }
}
```

The items should have a size of 60 if there's space to fit all items, or scale down to 30 if there isn't. Any ideas how I would accomplish that?

[image: Items fit in layout]

[image: Items should shrink to fit RowLayout]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there: Set `Layout.maximumWidth` instead of `Layout.preferredWidth` and make sure all the elements have `Layout.fillWidth` set to `true`. Also, the layout element itself must have the correct size for `fillWidth` to work. So replace `centerIn` with `fill` in this case.

Here is your snippet; corrected and rewritten to make it easier to try out different numbers of elements.

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.14
import QtQuick.Controls 2.14
import QtQuick.Window 2.14

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    id: root

    Item {
        id: col
        width: 300
        height: 200
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        RowLayout {
            id: row
            spacing: 10
            anchors.fill: parent

            Repeater {
                model: spinBox.value
                delegate: Rectangle {
                    Layout.minimumWidth: 30
                    Layout.maximumWidth: 60
                    Layout.preferredHeight: 20
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    color: ["red", "blue", "green", "green", "blue"][index % 5]
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // for visualization
    Rectangle {
        width: col.width
        height: col.height
        x: col.x
        y: col.y
        color: "black"
        opacity: 0.3
    }

    SpinBox {
        id: spinBox
        from: 1; to: 10
        value: 5
    }
}
```